# TypeError: $ is not a function in SonarQube 5.0 - 'link to JIRA'

Tags: sonarqube, jira-plugin

In sonar the 'Link to Jira' is not working. Nothing happens when I click the click and the HTML debug window shows:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
```

Is this a known issue for Sonar 5.0?
This seems unrelated to the JIRA plugin itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means jquery is not loaded.
Add below code in your html tag before using jquery in your code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks - so you reckon this is a bug in sonarqube then?